# In a JSP file how to access Servlet of another project using Request dispatcher

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have two project (Project1, Project2). Project1 contains a jsp page "index.jsp" and Project2 contains a servlet "HelloServlet".
From jsp page I am trying to forward/include  "HelloServlet". Below is the code..

index.jsp

```
<body>
<a href="/Project2/HelloServlet">Goto project2 servlet</a><!--This works Fine-->
<%
try{RequestDispatcher=null;
rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("../Project2/HelloServlet");//gives -> java.lang.NullPointerException
//rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Project2/HelloServlet");//gives -> The requested resource (/Project1/Project2/HelloServlet) is not available 
//rd.forward(request,response);
rd.include(request,response);
}
catch(Exception e){out.println("Exception occured: "+e);}
%>
</body>
```

HelloServlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
response.getWriter().println("Hello from project 2 servlet");
}
```

anchor tag works fine but RequestDispatcher gives null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is mandated per the Servlet specification. The Javadoc for `ServletRequest.getRequestDispacher` is clear on that (emphasize mine):

> RequestDispatcher getRequestDispatcher(String path)
>
> ...The pathname specified may be relative, although **it cannot extend outside the current servlet context**.

As a forward internally calls that method, you cannot forward to a page of a different application. You will have to do a redirect here. The redirect will work because you send the new URL to the browser asking it to go there. Here it could be:

```
<body>
    <c:redirect url="/Project2/HelloServlet"/>
</body>
```

using a nice and clean JSTL tag instead of a scriptlet.

If for any reason you cannot use JSTL, this scriptlet would to the same (but JSTL is shorter and nicer):

```
<body>
    <%
        response.sendRedirect("/Project2/HelloServlet");
    %>
</body>
```

Comment: but using redirect I cannot get the same request object available in HelloServlet

Comment: @SushilSharma: I know that forward and redirect are different. As you cannot use forward between different apps I just suggested redirect if it is appropriate. But you could pass parameters in the redirected URL that would be processed by the servlet `sendRedirect("/Project2/HelloServlet?param1=a&param2=b")`